# Can't find the module after extension is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create `VS Code` extension. It works when fine when I develop, however when I create the package and install it to `VS Code` it is failing with following error:

```
  ERR Cannot find module 'request': Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Function.t._load (c:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:729:537)
    at Function.t.getExtensionPathIndex.then.a._load (c:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:691:639)
    at Function.t.getExtensionPathIndex.then.r._load (c:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:655:197)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at n (c:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:15:874)
    at openBambooPlanUrlInBrowser.GIT.getGitBranchFromFileName (C:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\dUSER.markdown-table-of-contents-0.0.1\out\extension.js:397:41)
    at getGitBranchFromFileName.exec (C:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\dUSER.markdown-table-of-contents-0.0.1\out\extension.js:383:17)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
```

my code:

```
async openBambooPlanUrlInBrowser(fileName: string) {
    new GIT().getGitBranchFromFileName(fileName, (branch: string) => {
        var config: any = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('markdown-table-of-contents').get('bitbucketRepositories');
        for (var setting of config) {

            if (fileName.toLowerCase().startsWith(setting.folder.toLowerCase())) {
                branch = branch.replace('/', '-');
                let bambooHost = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('markdown-table-of-contents').get('atlassianBambooHost');
                const request = require('request');

                request(
                    {
                        url: `${bambooHost}/rest/api/latest/plan/${setting.bambooPlanKey}/branch/${branch}.json`,
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": 'Basic ' + vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('markdown-table-of-contents').get('atlassianAuthHash')
                        }
                    },
                    (error: string, response: string, body: string) => {
                        let planKey = JSON.parse(body).key;
                        vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse(`${bambooHost}/browse/${planKey}`));
                    }
                );

            }
        }
    });

}
```

dependencies from `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "clipboardy": "^1.2.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.24",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "util": "^0.11.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27"
}
```

root folder:

```
.gitignore
.vscode
.vscodeignore
depl.bat
markdown-table-of-contents-0.0.1.vsix
node_modules
out
package-lock.json
package.json
src
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

Comment: Check the package.json file in root directory ..make sure it's listed under dependencies.

Comment: it is listed there

Comment: This clearly means that your dependencies were not installed by VS Code when you installed your extension. It mostly happens when your package.json file is not present in the directory where your extension is installed. If the file is already there then you must check that if you have properly published your code.

Comment: package.json is there. All other packages working. I'm creating package manually. "vsce package" then "code --install-extension ext_name"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue? I'm facing a similar problem myself

Comment: yeah, I did. Unfortunately it was long time ago and I don't remember anything :)

Comment: Haha this is why you need to answer your own question :)

Comment: same problem, have you got solution ?

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was to run `npm install <package_name>` (notice no "-g") from the extension's code root folder. Vscode puts the extension in its [extension folder][1], navigate there to do `npm install`.

Example: for linux/mac

```
cd ~/.vscode/extensions
cd your.extension
npm install
```

This automatically added it to the devDependencies as well, and the extension worked perfectly from there on.

Comment: cd ~/.vscode-oss/extensions
Worked for me

Comment: Or you can include node_modules in your vsix in the first place

Comment: How do you include all node_modules?
Im having this problem with @xmldom/xmldom currently. Its in the folder and it is installed with no parameters but for some reason when installed that package is missing and VSCode fails to execute my extension

Comment: If its not listed in .vscodeignore and is in your root directory, it will be included with the extension bundle

Comment: I'm missing 'typescript'.  All other node_modules are in the folder.  Only typescript is missing.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to make sure `typescript` wasn't listed in `devDependencies` but instead *only* in `dependencies` inside the `package.json` file.

Simply moving it into `dependencies` forced the typescript node module to be included in my .vsix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and what helped was switching from npm to yarn by deleting the lock file and `node_modules` and running `yarn install`. `vsce package` then worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).